# Writing SEO for Homepage when homepage is set to display latest posts

Tags: plugins, themes, homepage, seo

I am using Yoast SEO and the JustWrite theme by Acosmin. In order for the theme to work properly, I am forced to set the homepage to display my latest posts.

Before with my previous theme, Neville by Acosmin, I set created a new page called home and gave is the Front Page template, and wrote SEO with the Yoast SEO plugin.

Now, there is no option to set the Page 'Home' as the front page. and with the homepage set as a static page 'Home', the theme cannot be edited.

So now, I've set the homepage to display my latest posts. Is there a way to edit the homepage SEO?

Answer (score 0):

As there's no page template called 'Front Page' anymore, I proceeded to the Theme Editor where I then edited the index.php file adding the following code right at the top of the file.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Front Page */ ?>
```

After I had saved the changes, I edited the Page and I then set the page called Home as the 'Front Page'. After the change in the index.php file, the Front Page option became available.

Now I am able to edit the SEO by going to the edit page section and at the bottom of the page, the Yoast SEO panel appears.